# Rounding to a variable number of decimal places

Tags: java, rounding

I want to round a given decimal to a number of decimal places that varies depending on user input. The other methods I know of (like `BigDecimal` or `String.format`) work with a fixed number of decimal places to round to. How do I round to a variable number of decimal places instead?

Comment: what do you mean by variable number of decimal place?

Comment: If the user specifies five places, it will round to five places - if the user specifies two, it will round to that, etc.

Comment: `BigDecimal.round()` takes a MathContext argument which is constructed with an `int setPrecision` *variable.* So what's your question?

Comment: I apologize, it seems like I hadn't quite understood how to use BigDecimal. However, the code `BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(num).setScale(numOfDecPlaces, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);` works differently for even and odd numbers - 0.5595 is rounded to 0.559, when rounding to three decimal places. How can I get it to become 0.600?

Answer (score -1):

You can use powers.

```
double mask = Math.pow(10, digits);
double result = Math.round(number * mask) / mask;
```

However, this method will not act well with larger numbers.

EDIT:

`BigDecimal` also has `setScale`. Provide the number of digits you require in the decimal part.

Comment: 'not act well with larger numbers' ... or smaller ones, or indeed work reliably at all.